# How to focus back on input after clicking button in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

**Use Case**

I am building a chat application so whenever a user types in a message in the chat box and clicks on send, ideally it should focus back on the input. Currently, this requires the user to click on the input again to start typing.

How can this be achieved in Svelte? I tried to use the `bind:this` and `use:` directives.

Edit: This is a Svelte Sapper project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create a reference to your rendered component using `bind:this={myComponentRef}`. Then to focus it, just call `myComponentRef.focus()`:

```html
<script>
  let message = ""

  let inputRef

  const onSend = () => {
    inputRef.focus()
  }
</script>

<input bind:this={inputRef} value={message}>
<button on:click={onSend}>Send Message</button>
```

Have a look to the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/1c5803a87d824e8987486eedc63a3a69?version=3.26.0).